# How can someone point out that there is a bug in the selected or highest-rated answer?

Tags: discussion, wrong-answers

I saw a bug in an answer that has a 10 character limitation.

That answer has been voted very positively because it works for under 10 characters.

What can be done?

Comment: You can comment on the answer. If you don't have enough reputation to comment yet, then there's not a lot you can do... Get some more rep by suggesting some good edits, and comment then...

Comment: Vote it down. If you want, add a comment highlighting the concern. If there's already a comment highlighting the flaw, up vote it. Move on. If the OP responds to the comment and pings you, and it satisfies your concerns, reverse the vote (or undo it).

Comment: If there's not already a comment on the answer saying so... comment and move along, or add an answer if you think there's enough improvement to be made

Comment: Post a **better** answer! But, if you take a lot from the 'buggy' one, then be sure to mention that you have done so. Something like, "Although the answer posted by XXX will work for less than 10 characters, the following will work more generally..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could post a comment pointing out the problem and maybe suggesting a solution.

But... you have not yet earned the commenting privilege. So you would have to wait until you gain (as of right now) another 6 reputation points to exercise this option.

Also, if you believe the answer is not good or useful because of this bug you could downvote it. But, since you do not have yet 125 reputation the vote wouldn't be very useful, since it wouldn't affect the answer score.

Suggesting an edit to fix the bug is generally a bad idea. This kind of edit doesn't usually go well for *suggested* edits, since reviewers may not be subject matter experts and may interpret your edit as a change of intent for the answer. Even with full edit privileges I wouldn't go that way unless it was pretty obvious the "bug" was a simple typo. I rather seek the author's approval to make an edit like that.

Nevertheless, there is no reputation requirement to post an **answer**. So you could simply post an alternative answer that addresses the bug of the other one (giving credit where credit is due). Anything else you can do to build upon this answer would be a great idea.

Comment: I do believe that there was a limitation on the rep point to answer on hot topic.

Answer (score 3):

Bookmark the question and come back to it as you get enough rep point to comment, downvote it, edit, etc.

This is a hind sighted answer, I should have done this in addition to the the above answer.